# calculating average and variance in c++

Tags: c++

I need help with my code... I have no idea whats wrong or how to fix it. I think it has something with declaring my variables and referencing but I am not entirely sure how to fix the bugs. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double calculate_average(int test_values[], int& size, int& sum, double& average) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += test_values[i];
    };
    return average = sum / i;
    };

double var(int test_values[], int size, double average, double& variance) {

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        variance += pow((test_values[j] - average), 2);
    };
    return variance;
};

int main() {

    int test_values[] = { 89, 95, 72, 83, 99, 54, 86, 75, 92, 73, 79, 75, 82, 53 };
    int size = sizeof(test_values);
    int sum;
    double average, variance;

    int calculate_average(int test_values[], int size, int sum, double average);
    int var(int test_values[], int size, double average, double variance);

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << test_values << endl;
    cout << average << endl;
    cout << variance << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, the best advice i can give is you should inspecting your code line by line with the debugger, and watch how variable values are actually changing.

Comment: " I have no idea whats wrong" is not a useful problem description. At the very least, you should be able to explain why you believe it's wrong.

Comment: expect output? actual output?

Comment: @NeedHelp101 - +1 for Conradin answer and take in count a point (5): you forget to inizialize `sum` (with `0`) and `variance` (with `0.0`)

Answer (score 3):

Your program has a lot of issues from which I'd like to point out some:

1. From how I understand your code, `int size = sizeof(test_values);` is supposed to be the number of integers in your test_values array. However, `sizeof(x)` returns the size of x in bytes. In your case, `size` is equal to 4*14=56, since int is four bytes big. To get what you want, you need to divide by the size of an int: `int size = sizeof(test_values) / sizeof(int);`. This sets `size` to 14.
2. There are unnessecary arguments for the functions `calculate_average()` and `var()`. The only thing you need is the data and the size.
3. You forgot to divide the variance by the size.
4. The syntax for calling the functions should be as follows:  `double average = calculate_average(test_values, size);` (analogously for `var()`). You only need to write the names of the variables you pass as arguments, the types are determined automatically.

Here is a working example similar to yours:

```
    #include <iostream>

    double average (int values[], int size) {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sum += values[i];
        }

        return sum / size;
    }

    double variance (int values[], int size) {
        double avg = average(values, size);
        double var = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var += (values[i] - avg) * (values[i] - avg);
        }

        return var / size;
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int test_values[] = { 89, 95, 72, 83, 99, 54, 86, 75, 92, 73, 79, 75, 82, 53 };
        int size = sizeof(test_values) / sizeof(*test_values);

        std::cout << "Average:\t" << average(test_values, size) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Variance:\t" << variance(test_values, size) << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

As it seems there is a bit of confusion on how to use functions correctly, so I strongly recommend to work through a tutorial on that topic (e.g. [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm)).